In hybris i am facing infinte recursion when converting ItemType to Json
I am new to sap hybris and given task to convert Model/itemType directly to Json.
 public List<ItemModel> getLatestItems(String tableName) {
        String queryString = String.format("SELECT {PK} FROM {%s} ORDER BY {creationtime} DESC", tableName);

        FlexibleSearchQuery query = new FlexibleSearchQuery(queryString);
        query.setCount(10);  // Limit to 10 rows

        SearchResult<ItemModel> searchResult = flexibleSearchService.search(query);
        return searchResult.getResult();
    }

tableName is basically Item type which is dynamic.
For example it can be CartModel or Product etc.
I want to convert the result from List to json.
Right now i am getting
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion
Is it possible to convert it to json using hybris or something else?

Your code seems incomplete, where is the conversion from Item Model to Json is happening ?
I haven't seen this way of dynamically getting Data for any model yet,
The reason it might be failing is that the Hybris Models can be complex, usually nested internally, so the conversion needs to be specified.
The actual recommended way is to individually do this for each Model, Controller -> Facade -> Service -> Dao.
You will find the example of Model data into Json conversion in the OCC module.
Where for example ProductModel is converted into ProductData (through converter/populator) and ProductData is converted into ProductWsDTO (through Orika Mapper).
